# Union field Table from a Table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have big Table in Access

```
ID IDParent  TimeRecord Value
1   1         00.00.01    10    
2   1         00.00.05    12    
3   2         00.00.03    4      
4   2         00.00.10    4
5   3         00.00.05    5   
6   3         00.00.10    6 
7   4         00.00.01    100
8   4         00.00.04    110
9   4         00.00.09    120
```

Need union table with IDParent = 4 and synchro with field TimeRecord

Result:

```
ID IDParent  TimeRecord Value  ValueIDParent4
1   1         00.00.01    10    100         // 100 because 00.00.01 between 00.00.01 and  00.00.04
2   1         00.00.05    12    110         // 110 because 00.00.05 between 00.00.04 and  00.00.09
3   2         00.00.03    4     100         // 100 because 00.00.03 between 00.00.01 and  00.00.04
4   2         00.00.10    4     120         // 120 because 00.00.10 between 00.00.09 and  last
5   3         00.00.05    5     110         // 110 because 00.00.05 between 00.00.04 and  00.00.09
6   3         00.00.10    6     120        // 120 because 00.00.10 between 00.00.09 and  last
```

How get result table in SQL?

Comment: you can do this with a join on TimeRecord, or is there a possibility that timerecord is in the table more than 2 times?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the output? Why is 100 assigned to the first row and 110 to the second?

Comment: How do you get the 2nd row in the result? There's no TimeRecord = 00.00.05 and IdParent = 4

Comment: Yes, timeRecord that not unique field may repeat more 2 times.

Comment: I think it's a scoring mechanism, if your time is 1sec to 3sec, then your score is 100, if it is 4sec or more then score is 110 etc...

Comment: Define the rules. What makes ID 8 bind with ID 2 in the expected result? What makes 9 seconds equal 10 seconds in the result? Is it by closest match, or by rounding up to closest, or some interval, or...?

Comment: I think I have it just creating a sql fiddle to make sure it works, hold on

Comment: what is your table data type?

Comment: @askeet i got your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ID as ID, t1.IDParent AS IDParent, 
          t1.TimeRecord AS TimeRecord, t1.Value AS Value,          
     COALESCE( (SELECT MAX(Value)
       FROM MyTable t2
        WHERE t2.TimeRecord <= t1.TimeRecord 
        AND t2.IDParent = 4),
     (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM MyTable)) 
              AS ValueIDParent4    
    FROM MyTable t1
    WHERE NOT t1.IDParent = 4
```

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/472f2/5

We get the highest amount of points you get for the time that is lower than your time (so the closest time that is lower than your time) Then I use the coalesce function to get the highest possible points you can get in case your time is too high to get a specific amount of points

more about coalesce at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

In Access 2010 you need to use function Nz

```
SELECT t1.ID as ID, t1.IDParent AS IDParent, 
          t1.TimeRecord AS TimeRecord, t1.NewValue AS NewValue,          
Nz( 
(SELECT MAX(NewValue) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.TimeRecord <= t1.TimeRecord AND t2.IDParent = 4),
(SELECT MAX(NewValue) FROM MyTable)
)  
AS ValueIDParent4  FROM MyTable t1 WHERE NOT t1.IDParent = 4
```

Comment: Thank you. But  function  COALESCE doesn't find in Access

Comment: the access alternative for coalesce is NZ(value1,alternative)